# RMarkdown ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am writing my PhD thesis in RMarkdown. Everything was rendering fine yesterday, today I added a few pieces of text with one reference (deleting it does not change the error message) and now, I get this error message:

> ! Undefined control sequence.  ...9}\selectfont {\global
> \setmainfont
> {DejaVu Sans}{}} l.3593 ...nt{\global\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}{}}}}
> & \multicolumn{3}{!{\colo...

The document consists of several child documents. I managed to track the error to one of the child documents by switching the individual child chunks off and on in the main document. BUT the line the error refers to seems to be from A DIFFERENT child document. All of the child documents knit OK when I try them separately.

I can get rid of the error when I use xelatex as the pdf engine but I would prefer to stick with pdflatex because of compatibility with some R packages.

My YAML:

```
title: ''
output: 
  pdf_document:
        latex_engine: pdflatex
        number_sections: TRUE
        pandoc_args: ['--lua-filter=section-bibliographies.lua']
always_allow_html: true
geometry: "left = 4cm, right = 2cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm"
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{sectsty}
  - \usepackage{paralist}
  - \usepackage{setspace}\spacing{1.5}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{dcolumn}
  - \usepackage{natbib}
  - \usepackage[nottoc, numbib]{tocbibind}
  - \usepackage{ragged2e}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{textgreek}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{titlesec}
classoption: twoside
bibliography: library.bib
reference-section-title: References
section-bibs-level: 2
citation_package: biblatex
csl: journal-of-ecology.csl
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to use non-standard fonts via `\setmainfont`; this requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: that's the problem, I don't know where. And it doesn't explain why it rendered OK before

Comment: You must have changed something that caused that, or a package was updated that caused that. Most likely the former. I'd suggest removing packages/elements one-by-one and see where you can find the issue. This may also imply that you create a minimal document and build it up to see where that type of functionality is introduced. Alternatively, just switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.